# Can multiple people connect to my desktop?

Tags: teamviewer

I am using Teamviewer to help teach my classmates something. I wanted to know if 3-4 people could use teamviewer simultaneously to connect to my PC.

Comment: I think screen casting software would be better than using team viewer

Comment: Use teamviewer in "Presentation Mode". See [https://meeting.teamviewer.com/en/features/](https://meeting.teamviewer.com/en/features/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use VNC Viewer on client machines and VNC Server on your host to provide that you want to do.